# Tracking AJAX form submission with Analytics

Tags: forms, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, dynamic-forms

So here's one that I've spent countless hours on trying to figure out already...

I'm working on a website set up on force.com and need to track form submissions with analytics. The only issue is that the form is dynamic and simply gives you a popup dialog for confirmation.

What are my best options on how to achieve tracking form submissions for this page?

```js
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        // Prepare a new record from template
        component.find("leadRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
            "Lead", // sObject type (entityApiName)
            null, // recordTypeId
            false, // skip cache?
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                var rec = component.get("v.newLead");
                var error = component.get("v.newLeadError");
                if (error || (rec === null)) {
                    console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
                    return;
                }
                
                component.set("v.simpleNewLead.LeadSource", "GreenLight Interest");
            })
        );
    },
    handleSaveLead: function(component, event, helper) {
                                // Get and set zipcode value
        var zipCodeInput = component.get("v.zipcode");
        if (zipCodeInput) {
                        component.set("v.simpleNewLead.PostalCode", zipCodeInput.toString());
        }

        var errorMessage = 'Complete this field.';
        var isValidEmail = true; 
        var emailField = component.find("leadEmail");
        var emailFieldValue = emailField.get("v.value");
        var regExpEmailformat = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;  
        
        // Validate email field
        if(emailFieldValue){   
            if(emailFieldValue.match(regExpEmailformat)){
                emailField.set("v.errors", [{message: null}]);
                $A.util.removeClass(emailField, 'error');
                $A.util.addClass(emailField, 'inputBorder');
                isValidEmail = true;
            }else{
                $A.util.addClass(emailField, "error");
                $A.util.removeClass(emailField, 'inputBorder');
                emailField.set("v.errors", [{message: "Please Enter a Valid Email Address"}]);
                isValidEmail = false;
            }
        }else{
            $A.util.addClass(emailField, "error");
            $A.util.removeClass(emailField, 'inputBorder');
            emailField.set("v.errors", [{message: errorMessage}]);
            isValidEmail = false;
        }
        if (
            component.get("v.simpleNewLead").FirstName &&
            component.get("v.simpleNewLead").LastName &&
            component.get("v.simpleNewLead").Email &&
            component.get("v.simpleNewLead").MobilePhone &&
            component.get("v.simpleNewLead").Company &&
            component.get("v.simpleNewLead").PostalCode &&
            component.get("v.simpleNewLead").PostalCode.length >= 5
        ) {
            component.find("leadRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
                if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

                    // Display success message
                    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        title: "Success!",
                        message: 'Thank you.',
                        key: 'info_alt',
                        type: 'success'
                    });
                    toastEvent.fire();                    
                } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    // handle the incomplete state
                    console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
                } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                    // handle the error state
                    console.log('Problem saving contact, error: ' +JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
                } else {
                    console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ',error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Add required field error for zip code field. If blank
            if (!zipCodeInput) { 
                var zip = component.find("zip");
                zip.set("v.errors", [{message: errorMessage}]);
                $A.util.removeClass(zip, "inputBorder");
                $A.util.addClass(zip, "error");
            }

            // Add required field error for other field. If blank
                                                var leadFields = component.find("leadField");
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < leadFields.length; i++) {
                var value = leadFields[i].get("v.value");
                if(value){
                    $A.util.removeClass(leadFields[i], "error");
                    $A.util.addClass(leadFields[i], "inputBorder");
                    leadFields[i].set("v.errors", []);
                }else{
                    leadFields[i].set("v.errors", [{message: errorMessage}]);
                    $A.util.removeClass(leadFields[i], "inputBorder");
                    $A.util.addClass(leadFields[i], "error");
                }
            }
        }
    },
    
    handleZipChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        // Validate zip code field lenght. Must be equal to or greator than 5
        helper.removeErrorMessage(component, event, "zip");
        var zip = component.find("zip");
        var zipInput = component.get("v.zipcode");
        console.log('zipInput>>>'+zipInput);
        var regPostalCode = /^[0-9]*$/gm; 
        var isNum = regPostalCode.test(component.get("v.zipcode"));
        var islessthan5digit = (component.get("v.zipcode").length < 5);
        console.log('isNum>>'+isNum);
        console.log('islessthan5digit>>'+islessthan5digit);
        
        if(!isNum || islessthan5digit) {
            zip.set("v.errors", [{message: "Zip Code should be 5 digits"}]);
            $A.util.removeClass(zip, "inputBorder");
            $A.util.addClass(zip, "error");
        }
        else{
            console.log('in else>>'); 
        }
    },
})
```

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="newLead" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="simpleNewLead" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newLeadError" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="zipcode" type="Integer" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    <force:recordData aura:id="leadRecordCreator"
                      fields="FirstName, LastName, Email, MobilePhone, PostalCode, Company"
                      targetRecord="{!v.newLead}"
                      targetFields="{!v.simpleNewLead}"
                      targetError="{!v.newLeadError}" />
    
    <!-- Display a header -->
    <div class="slds-box">
        
        <!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors -->
        <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.newLeadError))}">
            <div class="recordError">
                <ui:message title="Error" severity="error" closable="true">
                    {!v.newLeadError}
                </ui:message>
            </div>
        </aura:if>
        
        <!-- Display the new lead form -->
        <div class="slds-form--stacked slds-box">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-align_absolute-center">
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <div class="slds-form slds-form_horizontal slds-size--9-of-12 ">
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-id-01">First Name</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <ui:inputText aura:id="leadField" value="{!v.simpleNewLead.FirstName}" class="inputBorder"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-id-01">Last Name</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <ui:inputText aura:id="leadField" value="{!v.simpleNewLead.LastName}" class="inputBorder"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-id-01">Email</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--12-of-12">
                                <ui:inputEmail aura:id="leadEmail" value="{!v.simpleNewLead.Email}" class="inputBorder"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-id-01">Phone</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <ui:inputPhone aura:id="leadField" value="{!v.simpleNewLead.MobilePhone}" class="inputBorder"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-id-01">Zip Code</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <!--<ui:inputText aura:id="leadField" value="{!v.simpleNewLead.PostalCode}" class="inputBorder"/>-->
                                <!-- <ui:inputNumber  aura:id="zip" value="{!v.zipcode}" class="inputBorder" change="{!c.handleZipChange}" format="#####"/> -->
                                <ui:inputText  aura:id="zip" value="{!v.zipcode}" class="inputBorder" change="{!c.handleZipChange}" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-id-01">Company</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <ui:inputText aura:id="leadField" value="{!v.simpleNewLead.Company}" class="inputBorder"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{!c.handleSaveLead}" variant="brand" class="slds-m-top--medium slds-align_absolute-center"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have control over the code the easiest option would probably be to push an event (and additional data if you want) to the success callback of your ajax call. If I read the code correctly the proper place if in the if clase that starts with `saveResult.state === "SUCCESS"`, and you would modify it to:

```
    ...
    if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

                        // Display success message
                        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                        toastEvent.setParams({
                            title: "Success!",
                            message: 'Thank you.',
                            key: 'info_alt',
                            type: 'success'
                        });
                        toastEvent.fire();   
                        dataLayer.push({'event':'ajaxSuccess'})                 
                    } 
...
```

The line dataLayer.push({'event':'ajaxSuccess'})  means that you now have a GTM event that you can use in a trigger. The way this works is that GTM overwrites the "push" method of the dataLayer array to add a function that scans newly appended object for the "event" key, updates the internal data model of GTM and then fires all tags that have triggers with that event.

Likewise you could add error events if validation fails, or add additional key/value pairs to the  datalayer push to get additional variables within GTM.

Comment: Do you have to use tag manager to for this? I'm really unfamiliar with GTM

Comment: You don't have to, you could just as well stick Google Analytics code in there (but it's not usually a good idea to mix GTM implementation and inline GA code). Your question was tagged GTM, so I assumed you wanted to use that. The code changes for the datalayer go into the js code directly, and from there they emit an event that can be used to fire tags in GTM.

Comment: Ok, i've tested this and tried to look and see if the event fires in preview, but doesn't work. With GTM.

Comment: On another note, if i try to add a an onclick event to GA I cant because theres a salesforce code in there too.. how do I bypass that